# besides google and bing, what other search engine has an python api?

Tags: python, search-engine

Google and Bing are both free, for Google I use urllib and json to get the results. For Bing i use pyBing. Yahoo requires me to pay per 1000 queries, which I don't want to do for a homework assignment.

Is there any other SEs that has a python api? Or has something similar to Google's ajax googleapis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pySearch is no longer supported, the only way to search yahoo is to use their BOSS API.

The BOOS api would require payments for every 1000 queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Yahoo's [pYsearch](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-pysearch.html).